# Loop through dataset once

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm tasked with updating a few fields in a table that sits in a SQL 2005 db.  I'm currently using vb.net 2010 (.net 4) and am still learning this stuff so please be gentle.  If I've missed anything let me know and I'll get it in asap. Lastly, sorry this is so long, but I would be hard-pressed to create a description otherwise.

Besides the fields shown on the tables included, there are a few others but are not important in the overall scheme of this.  This table is used for labor tracking so an operator/user logs into a job and the following fields, are populated: EmployeeWorkID (primary key), EmployeeID (derived from a separate table), LoginDatetime (datetime stamp), and Status. Real world examples of the db table as it is populated:

> Table prior to running the app:

```
EmplWorkID EmplID  LoginDateTime     LogoutDateTime    Status LoggedIn LoggedOut
93464       376    2013-01-31 15:00  2013-01-31 17:25    C       0        0
93466       376    2013-01-31 17:26  2013-01-31 23:00    C       0        0
93468       376    2013-02-01 15:00  2013-02-01 23:00    C       0        0
93484       380    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 09:17    C       0        0
93485       380    2013-02-01 09:18  2013-02-01 11:22    C       0        0
93486       380    2013-02-01 11:23  NULL                A       0        0
93479       385    2013-01-31 07:03  2013-01-31 09:32    C       0        0
93481       385    2013-01-31 09:33  NULL                A       0        0
93473       385    2013-02-01 07:05  2013-02-01 09:13    C       0        0
93482       385    2013-02-01 09:14  2013-02-01 11:34    C       0        0
93480       385    2013-02-01 11:35  2013-02-01 13:41    C       0        0
93483       385    2013-02-01 13:42  2013-02-01 15:03    C       0        0
93478       394    2013-01-31 23:03  2013-02-01 00:53    C       0        0
93475       394    2013-02-01 00:54  2013-02-01 03:26    C       0        0
93476       394    2013-02-01 03:27  2013-02-01 05:39    C       0        0
93477       394    2013-02-01 05:44  2013-02-01 07:03    C       0        0
```

> Table after first run:

```
EmplWorkID EmplID  LoginDateTime     LogoutDateTime    Status LoggedIn LoggedOut
93464       376    2013-01-31 15:00  2013-01-31 17:25    C       1        0
93466       376    2013-01-31 17:26  2013-01-31 23:00    C       0        1
93468       376    2013-02-01 15:00  2013-02-01 23:00    C       1        1
93484       380    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 09:17    C       1        0
93485       380    2013-02-01 09:18  2013-02-01 11:22    C       0        0
93486       380    2013-02-01 11:23  2013-02-01 15:00    C       0        1
93479       385    2013-01-31 07:00  2013-01-31 09:32    C       1        0
93481       385    2013-01-31 09:33  2013-01-31 15:00    C       0        1
93473       385    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 09:13    C       1        0
93482       385    2013-02-01 09:14  2013-02-01 11:34    C       0        0
93480       385    2013-02-01 11:35  2013-02-01 13:41    C       0        0
93483       385    2013-02-01 13:42  2013-02-01 15:00    C       0        1
93478       394    2013-01-31 23:00  2013-02-01 00:53    C       1        0
93475       394    2013-02-01 00:54  2013-02-01 03:26    C       0        0
93476       394    2013-02-01 03:27  2013-02-01 05:39    C       0        0
93477       394    2013-02-01 05:44  2013-02-01 07:00    C       0        1
```

> Table after second run:

```
EmplWorkID EmplID  LoginDateTime     LogoutDateTime    Status LoggedIn LoggedOut
93464       376    2013-01-31 15:00  2013-01-31 17:25    C       1        0
93466       376    2013-01-31 15:00  2013-01-31 23:00    C     **1**      1
93468       376    2013-02-01 15:00  2013-02-01 23:00    C       1        1
93484       380    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 09:17    C       1        0
93485       380    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 11:22    C     **1**      0
93486       380    2013-02-01 11:23  2013-02-01 15:00    C       0        1
93479       385    2013-01-31 07:00  2013-01-31 09:32    C       1        0
93481       385    2013-01-31 07:00  2013-01-31 15:00    C     **1**      1
93473       385    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 09:13    C       1        0
93482       385    2013-02-01 07:00  2013-02-01 11:34    C     **1**      0
93480       385    2013-02-01 11:35  2013-02-01 13:41    C       0        0
93483       385    2013-02-01 13:42  2013-02-01 15:00    C       0        1
93478       394    2013-01-31 23:00  2013-02-01 00:53    C       1        0
93475       394    2013-02-01 00:54  2013-02-01 03:26    C       0        0
93476       394    2013-02-01 03:27  2013-02-01 05:39    C       0        0
93477       394    2013-02-01 05:44  2013-02-01 07:00    C       0        1
```

The second run shows the records that have been incorrectly updated.  The Login/LogoutDateTimes were updated as well as the LoggedIn flag.
What I need my vb app to do is set each employee's first LoginDateTime = Time & Attendance clock-in, and set their last LogoutDateTime = T&A clock out.  The included images show the first, and second runs of my app where it sets the LoggedIn and LoggedOut fields where necessary. However, this app will be ran several times during the day and will update new records as they are added.  The problem: (yeah I know...finally) subsequent runs of the application (see 'Table after second run:') pick up extra records that should not be updated.  For example, on the second run of the app the record for EmployeeWorkID = 93466 is picked up and the LoginDateTime is set to the T&A clock in (it would look like EmployeeWorkID = 93464), and the LoggedIn flag would be set to 1.  I've tried numerous ways of doing this both through SQL queries and vb code but am left without a solution. Here is the main SQL call that I make within the app, it may not look pretty but it is effective (for one run at least).

```
SELECT     
ew2.EmployeeWorkID
, qryID.Empl
, qryID.LoggedIn
, qryID.LoginDateTime
, ew2.LogoutDateTime
, qryID.RoundedInPunchDate
, qryID.RoundedOutPunchDate
, qryID.ScheduledInDateTime
, qryID.ScheduledOutDateTime
FROM         
(
 SELECT     
 ew.EmployeeID
 , stmE.Empl
 , stmE.STM_Employee_id
 , MIN(ew.LoginDateTime) AS LoginDateTime
 , vIO.RoundedInPunchDate
 , vIO.RoundedOutPunchDate
 , vES.ScheduledInDateTime
 , vES.ScheduledOutDateTime
 , ew.LoggedIn
FROM          
  tblEmployeeWork AS ew INNER JOIN
  tblEmployees AS e ON ew.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
  STROMBERG.StrombergTest.dbo.STM_Employee AS stmE ON e.Empl = stmE.Empl INNER JOIN
  STROMBERG.StrombergTest.dbo.v_BI_Employee_InOutPunches_AutoLogout2 AS vIO ON  
    stmE.STM_Employee_id = vIO.STM_Employee_id 
 AND CONVERT(varchar, ew.LoginDateTime, 101) = CONVERT(varchar, vIO.RoundedInPunchDate, 
   101) INNER JOIN
 STROMBERG.StrombergTest.dbo.v_BI_DailyEmplScheduleAndHoursWorked AS vES ON 
   vIO.STM_Employee_id = vES.STM_Employee_id AND 
 CONVERT(varchar, vIO.RoundedInPunchDate, 101) =   
     CONVERT(varchar,vES.ScheduledInDateTime, 101)
WHERE      
  (ew.LogoutDateTime BETWEEN '1/31/2013' AND DATEADD(d, 2, '1/31/2013')) AND     
  (vIO.RoundedInPunchDate BETWEEN '1/31/2013' AND DATEADD(d, 2, '1/31/2013')) AND 
  (ew.LoginDateTime BETWEEN '1/31/2013' AND DATEADD(d, 2, '1/31/2013'))
GROUP BY DAY(CONVERT(varchar, ISNULL(ew.LoginDateTime, vES.ScheduledInDateTime), 101)), 
  ew.EmployeeID, vIO.RoundedOutPunchDate, stmE.Empl, stmE.STM_Employee_id,  
  vIO.RoundedInPunchDate, vES.ScheduledInDateTime, vES.ScheduledOutDateTime, stmE.Empl, 
  ew.LoggedIn) AS qryID INNER JOIN
tblEmployeeWork AS ew2 ON qryID.EmployeeID = ew2.EmployeeID AND qryID.LoginDateTime = 
   ew2.LoginDateTime
ORDER BY ew2.EmployeeID
```

Comment: It really is not clear. What criteria in the SQL is picking up a record that you do **not* wish to update?

Comment: What is 'should' do is pick up the minimum datetime for the field, LoginDateTime, regardless of the flags being set.  After the second run, record # 93466 is updated but should not be.  Record # 93464 was updated on the 1st run but is still the MIN for the second run, yet it updates both records.

Comment: Never use `BETWEEN` with timestamps, especially on SQL Server (see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for why).  Why do you convert to character, only to call a date method on it?  Where's your `UPDATE` statement?  What do you _want_ the data to look like?  Why are you storing logged in/logged out, when this can be derived?  What about overlapping entries (logout time after login time of next record)?  What RDBMS and version?

Comment: Thanks for the link for the BETWEEN, I'll be reading that over asap and changing my queries accordingly.  the Logindatetime/logoutdatetime are when a user physically clocks/punches/logs into a shop order so there isn't a way to derive them, or if there is then I wouldn't know what to use as a reference.  The update query is just simple query which is called when a Logindatetime needs to be changed.  By that I mean the first clock/punch/log into an SO on any given day.  The data should look like it does in the table after the first run.  I see your point on the dates and will try to fix asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to do.  You want to set the first checkin of the day to 1 in the LoggedIn field and the last checkout of the day to 1 in the LoggedOut field.

This query will give you all the first checkins of the day and last checkouts of the day for every employee and every day.

```
select EmplID, min(LoginDateTime), max(LogoutDateTime)
group by EmplID, year(LoginDateTime), month(LoginDateTime), day(LoginDateTime)
```

Well, not exactly.  It will only work if no employee is checked in over mid-night.  Otherwise, the logout time will be when they logged out from starting on the given day.

So, the VB code can be used to set all the values from this result to 1, and everything else to 0.

Multiple runs on the same data will set the same values as before.  If more data is added, the results will fix the data, as long as the code will set values back to 0.

Performance can be dealt with by adding a where clause which will only change the data for the past N days.  For the last 7 days,

```
where LoginDateTime >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Marlin, you described exactly what I am attempting to do and have successfully done if only I ran the app one time.  Subsequent runs pick up extra records even though their MIN(logindatetime) is greater than the record prior to it for the same employee.

Comment: Your query is TL;DR.  The query I wrote shouldn't pick up extra records when the logindatetime is greater than the MIN.  If it does, SQLServer wouldn't be the reliable database I know it is.

Comment: Your query works great, thank you very much.  However, I do need to deal with third shift empl's so I still have another 'gotcha'.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: First you have to define what you want.  If you want the last logout of the day, then break out the max(LogoutDateTime) into it's own query with group by EmplID, year(LogoutDateTime), month(LogoutDateTime), day(LogoutDateTime).  However, what you might really want is the last logout for that shift, and the current group by is close.  Remember to consider the case where they logout before the end of shift before midnight, so that isn't the end of shift logout of the previous day's shift.  There is no single or easy way to handle third shift, and you need to start by defining what you want.

Comment: What I need was determined long ago when the initial version of our labor tracking software was written.  By that I mean if there are empl's that work part of day 1 but extends into day 2 and the bulk of their hours are on day 2 then they would be considered third shift.  In reality of course, there will be times when that doesn't work.  Regardless I need their first punch in, and last punch out per shift.  Then I'll need to deal with a slew of other cases (forgot punch out, still on a break, etc) but those will be 'easier' than this 3rd shift problem.  Thanks for the help, I'm almost there.

Comment: Again, it depends on what the definition of "extends into day 2" is, and what the definition of "the first punch in, and last punch out per shift" is.  In this question you asked about the first punch in and last punch out of the day and that's an answer I can give you.